# How to query on multiple similar string values using "contains" in Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql

I've an ADF pipeline whose failure logs I'm trying to query on. I need to analyse the log based on the parameters I'm using in my pipeline runs. My example query is as follows:

```
ADFPipelineRun
| project JobId, PLName, JobStatus, PL_param, Status
| where PLName == "org_daily_data_load"
| where Status == "Failed"
| where PL_param contains 'org_erp_sap'
```

This works. But I need to analyze results for various parameters. But the parameters are similar but not always same. They differ by date and time, as shown below:

parameters:

```
org_erp_sap_20201104_063418
ABC_ENV_D_20210329_174033
123_xyz_abc_20210801_101923
org_erp_sap_20210504_143418
123_xyz_abc_20210401_121923
```

As you see above, the dates are different but there is a common string part in the paremeters. If I want to check the log for these parameters, I'm having to manually change the parameter in the `where PL_param contains` clause for each query like below:

```
ADFPipelineRun
| project JobId, PLName, JobStatus, PL_param, Status 
| where PLName == "org_daily_data_load"
| where Status == "Failed"
| where PL_param contains 'org_erp_sap'


ADFPipelineRun
| project JobId, PLName, JobStatus, PL_param, Status 
| where PLName == "org_daily_data_load"
| where Status == "Failed"
| where PL_param contains 'ABC_ENV_D'


ADFPipelineRun
| project JobId, PLName, JobStatus, PL_param, Status 
| where PLName == "org_daily_data_load"
| where Status == "Failed"
| where PL_param contains '123_xyz_abc'
```

Is there a way to make the `contains` clause take multiple values just with the common string part irrespective of the date and timestamp information that follows? Something like below:

```
ADFPipelineRun
| project JobId, PLName, JobStatus, PL_param, Status 
| where PLName == "org_daily_data_load"
| where Status == "Failed"
| where PL_param contains 'org_erp_sap%' OR 'ABC_ENV_D%' OR '123_xyz_abc%'
```

This is my first time working with KQL and Azure Log Analytics, and I have no idea how to achieve this. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you want is to put all the variables in one place. For this you can use `let` statements, like this:

```
let PLName = "org_daily_data_load";
let StatusToLookFor = "Failed";
// etc...
ADFPipelineRun
| project JobId, PLName, JobStatus, PL_param, Status 
| where PLName == PLNameToLookFor
| where Status == StatusToLookFor 
| where PL_param contains 'org_erp_sap%' OR 'ABC_ENV_D%' OR '123_xyz_abc%'
```

By the way, if you're looking for full words, then it's much more efficient to use `has` instead of `contains` as it uses indexes. Also you'll be able to use more convenient syntax, like this:

```
| where PL_param has_any ('org_erp_sap%', 'ABC_ENV_D%', '123_xyz_abc%')
```

And if you want to declare this list at the beginning of the query, then you can do it like this:

```
let PLParamsToLookFor = dynamic(['org_erp_sap%', 'ABC_ENV_D%', '123_xyz_abc%']);
ADFPipelineRun
...
| where PL_param has_any (PLParamsToLookFor)
```